# Set checkbox style template label programmaticaly WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, styles

I created a style for a checkbox in WPF and created an array of those checkboxes programmaticaly. The style is as follows

```
<Style x:Key="deviceZoom" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <DockPanel x:Name="dockPanel">
                    <Canvas Width="24.15" Height="23">
                        <Image Source="/Resources/Icons/deviceUnselectedDiscrete.png" x:Name="DeviceImage" Width="12" Height="19" Canvas.Top="4"/>
                        <Border x:Name="borderDevice"
                                        CornerRadius="5"
                                        Width="20"
                                        Height="10"
                                        Background="#222528"
                                        BorderThickness="0"
                                        Canvas.Top="1"
                                        Canvas.Left="4.15">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="numBoards"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding=".1" FontSize="8" Foreground="White" Text="99"/>                                     
                        </Border>
                    </Canvas>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>    
</Style>
```

And then I create some checkboxes like so and add to the root canvas

```
    Style style = canvas.FindResource("deviceZoom") as Style;

    var deviceCheckbox = new CheckBox();
    canvas.Children.Add(deviceCheckbox);
    deviceCheckbox.Style = style;
    //Here I would like to set the label text
```

Now I would like to set from code behind a value to the label numBoards  every time I have new data, but I don't know how. I tried using Dynamic Properties but didn't manage to set them well since the checkbox is created programmaticaly, and tried with binding but without success

Comment: You should do this using the MVVM pattern. Generally in your case please try to explain what you are trying to achive in the first plac emaybe we can recommend a way to achive this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CheckBox has `Content` property. Binding TextBlock.Text in template to owner Content via TemplateBinding.

```
<Style x:Key="deviceZoom" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <DockPanel x:Name="dockPanel">
                    <Canvas Width="24.15" Height="23">
                        <Image Source="/Resources/Icons/deviceUnselectedDiscrete.png" x:Name="DeviceImage" Width="12" Height="19" Canvas.Top="4"/>
                        <Border x:Name="borderDevice"
                                        CornerRadius="5"
                                        Width="20"
                                        Height="10"
                                        Background="#222528"
                                        BorderThickness="0"
                                        Canvas.Top="1"
                                        Canvas.Left="4.15">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="numBoards"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                       Padding=".1" FontSize="8" Foreground="White"
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>                                     
                        </Border>
                    </Canvas>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>    
</Style>
```

Then you can assign Content and it will be displayed in TextBlock:

```
deviceCheckbox.Content = "I am deviceCheckbox";
```

Comment: Thank you I used this solution is simple and clean

Answer (score 0):

first, add UserControl. and add new property. it bind numBoards. XAML is ..

```
<UserControl x:Class="yourproject.myCheckBox"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:yourproject"
            mc:Ignorable="d" x:Name="rootCtrl"
            d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Canvas>
        <CheckBox DataContext="{Binding ElementName=rootCtrl}" >
            <CheckBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <DockPanel x:Name="dockPanel">
                        <Canvas Width="24.15" Height="23">
                            <Image Source="/Resources/Icons/deviceUnselectedDiscrete.png" x:Name="DeviceImage" Width="12" Height="19" Canvas.Top="4"/>
                            <Border x:Name="borderDevice"
                                        CornerRadius="5"
                                        Width="20"
                                        Height="10"
                                        Background="#222528"
                                        BorderThickness="0"
                                        Canvas.Top="1"
                                        Canvas.Left="4.15">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="numBoards"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding=".1" FontSize="8" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding NumBoards}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Canvas>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </CheckBox.Template>
        </CheckBox>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

Code is ..

```
public partial class myCheckBox : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    private string _NumBoards = "77";
    public string NumBoards
    {
        get
        {
            return _NumBoards;
        }
        set
        {
            _NumBoards = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("NumBoards");
        }
    }
    public myCheckBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and use myCheckBox control

```
var deviceCheckbox = new myCheckBox();
deviceCheckbox.NumBoards = "20";
canvas.Children.Add(deviceCheckbox);
```

Comment: if you are going to create a custom WPF control, then `NumBoards` should better be backed by a DependencyProperty. INotifyPropertyChanged belongs to view models. Views needs bindings, styles, etc, which can be achived via DP